# Retrieving specific data from SQL server Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

The two tables I am using are

```
Contacts (Contact_id, Contact_name,...)
Contacts_group_options (Contact_id, Group_id, Status)
```

I want to get all the contacts that are not part of a specific group from the `Contacts_group_options` table .
The problem is, if first table has `Contact_id`s 1, 2, 3, 4 and second table has `Contact_id`s 2, 3 for a `Group_id = 1`, I want result as 1 and 4. But I am getting 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4.

First 1 is compared with 2. Both are not same. Output 1,  then 2 with 2 same so don't output, 3 with 2 output 3, 4 with 2 output 4,1 with 3 output 1,2 with 3, output 2,3 with 3 dont output,4 with 3 output 4.
stored procedure is:

```
Select 
    m.Contact_id,
    m.Contact_code,
    m.Contact_name,
    m.Phone_number,
    m.Mail_id,
    m.Designation,
    m.Department,
    m.User_id,
    m.User_type,
    m.Status
from 
    Contacts as m,
    Contact_group_options as b
    ,@tblType_contacts2group as i
where
    b.Group_id = i.Group_id
    and m.Contact_id != b.Contact_id
```

Comment: What is `tblType_contacts2group` for?

Comment: [Avoid old join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: will you please write your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with a simple `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Contacts AS c
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM Contact_group_options
        WHERE
            Group_id = 1
            AND Contact_id = c.Contact_id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
-- NOT EXISTS
SELECT C.*
FROM Contacts C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Contacts_group_options WHERE Group_id = 1 AND C.Contact_id)

-- NOT IN
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE Contact_id NOT IN (SELECT Contact_id FROM Contacts_group_options WHERE Group_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result set includes so many rows because you actually have three tables there: Contacts, Contact_group_options and @tblType_contacts2group.

Maybe you wanted to write something like this:

```
-- compacted for to make it more readable
Select 
    m.Contact_id, m.Contact_code, m.Contact_name, m.Phone_number,
    m.Mail_id, m.Designation, m.Department, m.User_id, m.User_type, m.Status
from Contacts as m
where not exists (select 1 from @tblType_contacts2group as i where i.Group_id = m.Group_id)
```

NOTE: Since @tblType_contacts2group is not clearly defined in your example, above query might not get the correct results.

As already Felix mentioned, you should always use proper joins. E.g. the above query could be like this:

```
Select 
    m.Contact_id, m.Contact_code, m.Contact_name, m.Phone_number,
    m.Mail_id, m.Designation, m.Department, m.User_id, m.User_type, m.Status
from Contacts as m
   left join @tblType_contacts2group i on i.Group_id = m.Group_id
   where i.Group_id IS NULL    -- any non-null column from i can be used here
```

However, keep in mind that, usually, LEFT JOIN with IS NULL is slower that NOT EXISTS equivalent.